# Keycode returning 0 in javascript and jquery for android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

My question is similar to the [this link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=68858) , i am not getting the e.keycode/e.which value for in the specific version of android.
Is there any workaround for that ?

Comment: Define "specific version". Also on which event you're trying to detect evt.keyCode?

Comment: i have checked this on android 4.4.4
and i am trying both the events,
evt.keyCode and evt.which both return 0.

Comment: The link i mentioned tells exact devices and version.